# Haskell - What does `scanl` do in this expression

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

New to Haskell and Functional Programming

In Haskell (ghci) what does scanl do in the following expressions?

- `scanl (+) 0 [1,3..]`
- `scanl (*) 1 [1..]`

At first I thought it makes an infinite list of odd numbers where it successively adds them however this doesn't sound right. What does both those expressions do?

Thank you

Comment: Did you take a look at [the function's documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl)?

Comment: "*it successively adds them*" - yes, exactly that. Why does this not sound right to you?

Comment: If this hasn't been covered yet, a common way to find the documentation of a given Haskell function is to direct your browser to a web site known as [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) and then type the name of the function (or maybe a type signature) into the top-left search window.

Answer (score 4):

`scanl` is just like `foldl` except for it gives you a list of intermediate results instead of just the final one.  Understanding it helps understanding `foldl` and vice versa.  So, for example, whereas `foldl (+) 0` finds the sum of all elements of a list, `scanl (+) 0` shows you all the intermediate sums leading up to it:

```
ghci> scanl (+) 0 [1,1,1,2,5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10]
-- +1 +1 +1 +2  +5
```

Similarly, since `foldl (++) ""` concatenates a bunch of stirngs, `scanl (++) ""` shows you the intermediate concatenations:

```
ghci> scanl (++) "" ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"]
["", "foo", "foobar", "foobarbaz", "foobarbazquux"]
```